# Setting outline-%d foreground according to dark or light theme

Tags: faces, themes, outline

I want to adapt this so that the colours used depend upon whether a dark theme (use `pigment-darkbg`) or light theme (use `pigment-lightbg`) is being used.  What can I do ?

Would the following be proper ?

```
(defun outl-tyface ()
  (interactive)
  (let* ( (pigment-darkbg  '("#ff62d4" "#9f80ff" "#fe6060" "#fba849"
                             "#4fe42f" "#4fafff" "#f0dd60" "#FFFFFF"))
          (pigment-lightbg '("#1f1fce" "#006800" "#b60000" "#605b00"
                             "#a8007f" "#005f88" "#904200" "#7f10d0"))
         (pigment
           (if (eq (frame-parameter nil 'background-mode) 'dark)
               pigment-darkbg
             pigment-lightbg)) )

    (dotimes (i 8)
      (let ((outl-name (intern (format "outline-%d" (1+ i))))
            (outl-colr (nth i pigment)))
        (set-face-foreground outl-name outl-colr)))))
```

Comment: You said "adapt _this_" but there is no code to adapt, there is only the code that you offer as possibly being proper. In addition, there are two questions here. Please only keep one of them, preferably the second one, and please edit the question so that we know what you have tried and what the result was.